# Limit and request decleration

Tags: kubernetes

it's needed to add `"" OR ''` to the request/limit configurations?
For example:

```
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 300Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 1m
      memory: 50Mi
```

vs.

```
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "100m"
      memory: "300Mi"
    requests:
      cpu: "1m"
      memory: "50Mi"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. In the case you mention.

The only reason you will have to add quotes surrounding values is when there's room for confusion, converting your YAML into a JSON.

In your sample, you probably noticed that both versions work. Not setting any quotes doesn't end up with an error.

However, the following would be invalid:

```
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 300Mi
```

If you try to create a workload with a resource limits such as above, you would get an error: object is invalid. To fix it, you will have to quote your cpu limit, such as:

```
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: 300Mi
```

This has to do with your client, converting this yaml into a JSON before posting to the API. A JSON that says `"resource": { "limits": { "cpu": 1 } }` is valid on paper. Although from the server perspective, you're using an integer, when a string is expected (as per podSpec / resources schema).

So: no, it is not needed to have `""` or `''` surrounding resource requests or limits, most of the time. Until your requested value can be casted as an integer.